# Significant difference on boxcox transformed data where raw data means overlap

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, data-transformation

I boxcox transformed my data, created a linear model in r,
then did anova(linear_model).

I did this because my data was non-normal and was not compatible with any generalized linear model.

My means (+/- the SEM) of the two groups in the raw data are 0.089 +/- 0.03 and 0.89 +/- 0.006 so they do overlap.

For the transformed values the means 4.54 +/- 0.04 and 4.17 +/- 0.08 so the transformed values do **not** overlap, and the analysis of variance is saying there is a significant difference between the two groups

Can anyone help explain why this is happening? As far as I see it, there shouldn't be a significant difference as the means of the raw data overlap.

Comment: Advice about what?  WHy would you boxcox the data?

Comment: @DemetriPananos because I don't think there is a signficant difference in my raw data. My data was non normal and not compatible with a generalized linear model.

Comment: What justification do you have for the data being not normal?  Additionally, if there is no significant difference on the raw data, how does that justify transforming the data?

Comment: @DemetriPananos the residuals vs fitted plot from the linear model shows the data is non normal. I need to do a statistical test on it for my paper to find out if there is a significant diffference. Attended advanced stats course which taught us way to do this was linear model or generalised linear model in R and then do anova(linear_model). my data is not compatible with GLMs so I transformed my data so I could do a linear model.

Comment: Anova is usually robust to departures from normality if you have biggish samples.  There may be a more appropriate likelihood for your data, but the justification of transforming your data only after failing to reject the null sounds a like like p hacking unless you have good reason to transform the data prior to analyzing it. Can you tell us what you're research question is?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I transformed my data because the residuals are not normally distributed. It's not an proper anova I've done either (the command for that is aov() in R), it's a linear model followed by anova() which displays an analysis of variance table. Was told this is the best way to do it as traditional anovas are outdated. Can't run a linear model and do this without transforming the data because the residuals vs fitted for the linear model of my raw data shows the residuals aren't normally distributed so any conclusions made from the linear model wouldn't be supported

Comment: @DemetriPananos research question is to see if the width of peaks I have generated in my experiment are significantly different. See these posts as to why I did what i did https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505376/glm-instead-of-mann-whitney

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505918/non-normal-residuals-even-after-transforming-data-and-generalised-linear-models

I found a boxcox transform solved the heterodescacity problem